# Masking a date in oracle without changing year

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a script I can run to mask a date just fine.  My requirements are that the date can't be moved forward, the calendar year cannot change and 01-jan-xx cannot change.

My current code changes the date randomly between -1 and -85 days; however I'm unsure if it should be changed to query off Julian date maybe so that I don't change the calendar year...open for any insight or help.

```
create or replace FUNCTION a_function (a_date DATE)
RETURN DATE
AS
a_val    NUMBER;
a_val1   NUMBER;
a_date   DATE;
a_date1  DATE;
BEGIN
a_val := DBMS_RANDOM.VALUE (1, 85);
a_date := a_date + a_val;
IF TO_CHAR (a_date, 'YYYY') <> TO_CHAR (a_date, 'YYYY')
THEN
  a_val1 := DBMS_RANDOM.VALUE (-1, -85);
  a_date1 := a_date + (a_val1);
  RETURN a_date1;
 ELSE
  RETURN a_date;
END IF;
END;
```

Comment: Please edit your question and provide sample data and desired results.

Comment: sample data would be any date:

01-Jan-00  This date should never change (because of it being January 1st.

07-July-34  Can change to any date within the year of 1934.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two options: first, to get a random earlier date/time; and second, to get a random earlier date (with no time component).

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/9e039/1)

**Oracle 11g R2 Schema Setup**:

```
CREATE FUNCTION get_Random_Earlier_Datetime(
  in_date DATE
) RETURN DATE
AS
BEGIN
  RETURN TRUNC( in_date, 'Y' ) + DBMS_RANDOM.VALUE( 0, in_date - TRUNC( in_date, 'Y' ) );
END;
/

CREATE FUNCTION get_Random_Earlier_Day(
  in_date DATE
) RETURN DATE
AS
BEGIN
  RETURN TRUNC( in_date, 'Y' ) + FLOOR( DBMS_RANDOM.VALUE( 0, in_date - TRUNC( in_date, 'Y' ) ) );
END;
/
```

**Query 1**:

```
SELECT DATE '2015-01-01' + LEVEL - 1 AS "Date",
       get_Random_Earlier_Datetime( DATE '2015-01-01' + LEVEL - 1 ),
       get_Random_Earlier_Day( DATE '2015-01-01' + LEVEL - 1 )
FROM   DUAL
CONNECT BY LEVEL <= 10
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/9e039/1/0)**:

```
|                      Date | GET_RANDOM_EARLIER_DATETIME(DATE'2015-01-01'+LEVEL-1) | GET_RANDOM_EARLIER_DAY(DATE'2015-01-01'+LEVEL-1) |
|---------------------------|-------------------------------------------------------|--------------------------------------------------|
| January, 01 2015 00:00:00 |                             January, 01 2015 00:00:00 |                        January, 01 2015 00:00:00 |
| January, 02 2015 00:00:00 |                             January, 01 2015 14:11:37 |                        January, 01 2015 00:00:00 |
| January, 03 2015 00:00:00 |                             January, 01 2015 09:24:25 |                        January, 01 2015 00:00:00 |
| January, 04 2015 00:00:00 |                             January, 01 2015 00:45:22 |                        January, 03 2015 00:00:00 |
| January, 05 2015 00:00:00 |                             January, 03 2015 11:54:39 |                        January, 04 2015 00:00:00 |
| January, 06 2015 00:00:00 |                             January, 05 2015 03:55:55 |                        January, 01 2015 00:00:00 |
| January, 07 2015 00:00:00 |                             January, 04 2015 01:12:23 |                        January, 02 2015 00:00:00 |
| January, 08 2015 00:00:00 |                             January, 06 2015 22:10:37 |                        January, 02 2015 00:00:00 |
| January, 09 2015 00:00:00 |                             January, 06 2015 10:47:04 |                        January, 04 2015 00:00:00 |
| January, 10 2015 00:00:00 |                             January, 06 2015 07:20:25 |                        January, 08 2015 00:00:00 |
```

Answer (score 2):

I'd try something like

```
create or replace function a_function( a_date date )
  return date
is
  l_max_days integer;
begin
  -- Don't change dates that occur on the first of the year2
  if trunc(a_date) = trunc(a_date, 'YYYY')
  then
    return a_date;
  end if;

  l_max_days := to_number( to_char( a_date, 'DDD' ) ) - 1;
  return trunc(a_date, 'YYYY') + dbms_random.value( 0, l_max_days );
end;
```

This gets the day of the year for `a_date`, subtracts 1, and then generates a number of days between 0 and l_max_days.  So if `a_date` is, say, Jan 10, l_max_days is 9 and we add between 0 and 8 days to the first of the year giving us a date between Jan 1 and Jan 9.  You could remove the `- 1` from `l_max_days` if you want to allow the returned date to match the input date.